What poster is this?
From one of the last scenes in Scary Movie 2, where Cindy is on the phone with her dad. She is in a room with the bird and you can see 3 posters on the wall, one in the middle is for 2 pac. I want to know which one is on the right? 

Can you find a photo of the scene?  How about the timestamp of where it occurs in an online video?

That was a fun challenge...Found the scene, then looked for album covers that came out in 2000 (since the film came out in 2001)...

It's a Limp Bizkit poster from their Chocolate Starfish and the Hot Dog Flavored Water album:


